# demo website for OBIEE analyses

Tags: obiee

I am new on OBIEE and during a course of Oracle they mentioned a demo site where you can find a lot of examples of analytics reports. The URL was 
http://slc02ojq.oracle.com:7780/analytics/
This link doesn't work anymore and I managed to find a new link but it doesn't work neither. 
Do someone know where I can find those demo sites?

Answer (score 1):

All public SampleApps have been taken down and removed.

Only 2 servers hosting mobile demos are still up but those are for use with the Android/iPhone apps and not running the full SampleApp functionality accessible to you.

Comment: that is sad to hear

Comment: Maybe there will be a new one coming online once they have transitioned everything to OAC.